# Identity Server 4 Failed to Validate the Token from localhost for the protected API

Tags: identityserver4

Scenario

- localhost & 192.168.0.10 refer to the same machine called MyPC
- Identity server is running on that "MyPC"
- UI uses "localhost" to communicate with Identity Server
- The protected API uses "192.168.0.10" to communicate with Identity Server
- UI & API talk to each other and authenticated by an Identity Server

In the above scenario, If I use Identity Server 3, everything is fine; however the problem started when I switch to Identity Server 4 (the latest version). I got this error in the API

> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException: IDX10205: Issuer validation failed. Issuer: 'localhost:9987'......

That error will go away if I use the same IP address (localhost or 192.168.0.10) for both UI & API to communicate with the Identity Server.

Could anyone point me to the direction to fix this? I do need the ability to access Identity Server using either 127.0.0.1, localhost, Lan Addresses, Wan Addresses?

This is code that I am using in the API Startup:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityServerAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.Authority = Configuration.GetSection("URL").GetSection("IdentityServerURL").Value;
                x.ApiSecret = Configuration.GetSection("Resource").GetSection("APISecrets").Value;
                x.ApiName = Configuration.GetSection("Resource").GetSection("APIName").Value;
                x.SupportedTokens = SupportedTokens.Both;
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            });
```

P/S: I had done research on this but there wasn't any clear answer on this.

Answer (score 0):

The IdentityServer4 server will include an "Issuer" in the JWT token. You can double check e.g. using [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) what that is. From [the relevant docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/options.html):

> Set the issuer name that will appear in the discovery document and the issued JWT tokens. It is recommended to not set this property, which infers the issuer name from the host name that is used by the clients.

If you do custom naming, aliasing, ports, subdomains, and whatnot, then you could go ahead and set it manually anyways (both on the server side and on the validation side), or set issuer validation off (perhaps only in dev) altogether.